# retrieve the country with facebook connect

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

How can i retrieve the country with facebook connect and the city if possible ? i tried this

```
 @"SELECT uid, name, pic ,birthday_date , sex, locale, current_location ,contact_email FROM user WHERE uid=me()", @"query",
```

but the current_location is , and the local is en_US because I use facebook in English but not the country .

I have another question please,can I use the acess token I had with any application? For example I use facebook connect iphone with an ios application, can i put the acess token in a database in my server and use it with other applications, such as php?